# Consistency behaviour of ConcurrentHashMap.keySet().stream()

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, concurrentmodification

What consistency behaviour can I expect from this `modify` method with a `ConcurrentHashMap`?

```java
// map is filled concurrently from multiple threads
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


public void modify(Object newValue) {
  map.keySet().stream()
    .filter(/* some filter */)
    .forEach(k -> {
      if (/* k has some property */) {
        map.put(k, newValue);
      } else {
        map.remove(k);
      }
    });
}
```

I find it difficult to get a definitive answer from reading the Javadocs, how `keySet()`, `stream()`, and modification of the map entry inside the stream interact together.  I know that `keySet()`'s `spliterator` is [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly), so the stream should at least iterate through all the elements, as they were present at some point in the past, only once. And that modifying the data source during stream execution is supported for concurrent collections (see [Non-interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference)). It might be relevant that I am always modifying the current key only and not touching other map entries in the `foreach` lambda.

So is the above code "all good" in a weakly consistent manner, or are there some caveats which I should be aware of?

---

*Note:* The above code also doesn't make really sense like that, but this is simplified code with other non-concurrency-related aspects left out.

It's possible that the code can be written better using different methods, e.g. `forEach` on the map itself. Feel free to suggest improvements if it adds to the answer, but please provide only answers that answer my actual question. I am not asking how to make this better, I am merely wondering how all the parts interact in my example.

Comment: Can we assume that the “map is filled concurrently from multiple threads” step has been completed prior to the Stream operation and there are no other concurrent modifications during the Stream operation? Or generally, that atomicity of the updates made by the Stream operation is not required?

Comment: @Holger No, actually the map could be arbitrarily modified concurrently to the "modify" method. Atomicity is required in the lowest-level sense (don't break the data structure), but not in a higher-level sense. Let me clarify my requirements in concrete examples: a) Any modification to entries that I am NOT touching in "modify" should not interfere in the outcome of my method or of those other modifications; b) Any modifications to the entries that I AM touching should not break the "modify" stream, nor the map, nor the individual entries, but I don't expect a sensible "global truth" outcome.

Comment: I added a filter stream operation to the code just to make it a bit more realistic, so my comment above also makes a bit more sense. But the question still would be exactly the same without the filter, I don't think it makes a difference from a concurrency perspective.

Comment: The iteration and modification logic bears no problems but when there are concurrent modifications, you have to be aware that by the time you’re performing the check of `if (/* k has some property */)`, some other thread could remove the mapping and `map.put(k, newValue);` would re-add it. Likewise, when you execute `map.remove(k);` and a different thread adds the same key afterwards, it’s not clear whether you could encounter that key again during the same iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> the stream should at least iterate through all the elements, as they were present at some point in the past, only once

I would remove "all" from the phrase, because this wording might give a false impression that the stream iterates over some atomic snapshot of the whole `ConcurrentHashMap`.
In reality the stream might reflect (some) modifications of the map, which happened after the stream was created. As a result, it is possible that the first and the last keys emitted by a stream have never been in the map at the same time.

The [wording for weakly consistent](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/package-info.java#L222) (referenced by [the keySet()'s javadoc](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1229)) mentions that:

> they *[i.e. Iterators and Spliterators]* are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

It is also mentioned in another words [in the javadoc](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L3309) for `Traverser` (the base class for iterators and spliterators) in `ConcurrentHashMap`:

> Encapsulates traversal for methods such as containsValue; also serves as a base class for other iterators and spliterators.
>
> Method advance visits once each still-valid node that was reachable upon iterator construction. It might miss some that were added to a bin after the bin was visited, which is OK wrt consistency guarantees.

Also "some point in the past" is pretty vague as well: you cannot see a key which was removed from the map before the `stream()` was created.