Concurrent HashMap weak consistency missing past keys during iteration - multi thread pub/sub
Noticing weird behavior with ConcurrentHashMap iteration.
Scenario:

Single publisher thread constantly adds new keys to the concurrent hashmap. Note keys are added in sequential order.
Multiple subscriber thread tries to read all present values in the concurrent hashmap.

Many subscribers seem to be missing keys which were added much earlier. Example, when a subscriber reads the map with size 100. It is expected that the subscriber will see atleast keys from 0 to 99. However, it seems it does not return all the keys. Below is the sample code that reproduces the issue. In other words, even after example key 100 is added in the map, on random reads, key 100 appear to be missing.
In terms of explanation, I am thinking that when a key is being resolved by chaining and a read all requests comes in, then the collision related keys are not returned. However, I am looking if anyone else has seen this and can provide a better explanation for the below behavior.
Below code has 3 variants:

one where the problem shows up (test())
one where if the map is kept big enough and collisions ~"do not occur", then complete view is received on random basis (testWithNoCollisions).
one where locks are used to ensure when a subscriber is reading the whole map, then the writers are blocked (testWithLocks).

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ConcurrentHashMapWeakConsistency {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        test();
//        testWithNoCollisions();// Sometimes it passes when there is no collision
//        testWithLocks();// This one works but it has external synchronize mechanism.
    }

    public static void test() throws InterruptedException {
        var map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

        var publisher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        var totalMessages = 1_000_000;
        publisher.submit(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalMessages; i++) {
                var key = "key-" + i;
                map.put(key, i);
                if (i % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.printf("Published %d messages.\n", i);
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("Published all %d messages\n", totalMessages);
        });

        var subscriberCount = 100;
        var subscribers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        var subsLatch = new CountDownLatch(subscriberCount);

        IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(subscriberId -> subscribers.submit(() -> {
            try {
                var existingKeys = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());
                var size = existingKeys.size();

                //Note the keys are inserted by publisher in sequential order.
                // Hence, existing keys values should have all keys from range 0 to size-1
                // This is where weak consistency shows up.
                var missingKeys = IntStream.range(0, size).filter(num -> !existingKeys.contains("key-" + num))
                        .sorted()
                        .boxed()
                        .toList();

                if (!missingKeys.isEmpty()) {
                    var sortedExistingKeys = existingKeys.stream()
                            .sorted((k1, k2) -> Integer.parseInt(k1.split("-")[1]) - Integer.parseInt(k2.split("-")[1]))
                            .toList();
                    var start = sortedExistingKeys.get(0);
                    var end = sortedExistingKeys.get(sortedExistingKeys.size() - 1);
                    var missingStart = "key-" + missingKeys.get(0);
                    var missingEnd = "key-" + missingKeys.get(missingKeys.size() - 1);
                    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Subscriber %d missing %d keys! Result key range is [ %s, %s]. However, many numbers in range [ %s, %s ] are missing", subscriberId, missingKeys.size(), start, end, missingStart, missingEnd));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            } finally {
                subsLatch.countDown();
                System.out.printf("Subscriber %d finished reading from map.\n", subscriberId);
            }
        }));


        subsLatch.await();
        publisher.shutdownNow();
        subscribers.shutdownNow();
    }

    public static void testWithNoCollisions() throws InterruptedException {
        var map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>(1_000_000, .25f);

        var publisher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        var totalMessages = 10_000;
        publisher.submit(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalMessages; i++) {
                var key = "key-" + i;
                map.put(key, i);
                if (i % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.printf("Published %d messages.\n", i);
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("Published all %d messages\n", totalMessages);
        });

        var subscriberCount = 100;
        var subscribers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        var subsLatch = new CountDownLatch(subscriberCount);

        IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(subscriberId -> subscribers.submit(() -> {
            try {
                var existingKeys = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());
                var size = existingKeys.size();

                //Note the keys are inserted by publisher in sequential order.
                // Hence, existing keys values should have all keys from range 0 to size-1
                // This is where weak consistency shows up.
                var missingKeys = IntStream.range(0, size).filter(num -> !existingKeys.contains("key-" + num))
                        .sorted()
                        .boxed()
                        .toList();

                if (!missingKeys.isEmpty()) {
                    var sortedExistingKeys = existingKeys.stream()
                            .sorted((k1, k2) -> Integer.parseInt(k1.split("-")[1]) - Integer.parseInt(k2.split("-")[1]))
                            .toList();
                    var start = sortedExistingKeys.get(0);
                    var end = sortedExistingKeys.get(sortedExistingKeys.size() - 1);
                    var missingStart = missingKeys.get(0);
                    var missingEnd = missingKeys.get(missingKeys.size() - 1);
                    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Subscriber %d missing %d keys! Result key range is [ %s, %s]. However, many numbers in range [ %s, %s ] are missing", subscriberId, missingKeys.size(), start, end, missingStart, missingEnd));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            } finally {
                subsLatch.countDown();
                System.out.printf("Subscriber %d finished reading from map.\n", subscriberId);
            }
        }));


        subsLatch.await();
        publisher.shutdownNow();
        subscribers.shutdownNow();
    }

    public static void testWithLocks() throws InterruptedException {
        var map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

        var publisher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        var totalMessages = 1_000_000;
        var subscriberActive = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        publisher.submit(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalMessages; i++) {
                var key = "key-" + i;
                // get the subscriber lock
                while (!subscriberActive.compareAndSet(false, true)) ;
                map.put(key, i);
                subscriberActive.compareAndSet(true, false);
                if (i % 10000 == 0) {
                    System.out.printf("Published %d messages.\n", i);
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("Published all %d messages\n", totalMessages);
        });

        var subscriberCount = 100;
        var subscribers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        var subsLatch = new CountDownLatch(subscriberCount);

        IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(subscriberId -> subscribers.submit(() -> {
            try {
                while (!subscriberActive.compareAndSet(false, true)) ;
                var existingKeys = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());
                subscriberActive.compareAndSet(true, false);

                var size = existingKeys.size();

                //Note the keys are inserted by publisher in sequential order.
                // Hence, existing keys values should have all keys from range 0 to size-1
                // This is where weak consistency shows up.
                var missingKeys = IntStream.range(0, size).filter(num -> !existingKeys.contains("key-" + num))
                        .sorted()
                        .mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                if (!missingKeys.isEmpty()) {
                    var sortedExistingKeys = existingKeys.stream()
                            .sorted((k1, k2) -> Integer.parseInt(k1.split("-")[1]) - Integer.parseInt(k2.split("-")[1]))
                            .toList();
                    var start = sortedExistingKeys.get(0);
                    var end = sortedExistingKeys.get(sortedExistingKeys.size() - 1);
                    var missingStart = missingKeys.get(0);
                    var missingEnd = missingKeys.get(missingKeys.size() - 1);
                    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Subscriber %d missing %d keys! Result key range is [ %s, %s]. However, many numbers in range [ %s, %s ] are missing", subscriberId, missingKeys.size(), start, end, missingStart, missingEnd));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            } finally {
                subsLatch.countDown();
                System.out.printf("Subscriber %d finished reading from map.\n", subscriberId);
            }
        }));


        subsLatch.await();
        publisher.shutdownNow();
        subscribers.shutdownNow();
    }
}

It appears that  in ConcurrenHashMap, when concurrent writes and full reads of the map are done, then the read returns results which are often missing keys from the past. I was expecting that it would provide a snapshot of the map at a point of time. However that does not seem to be the result based on the above test code.

By the way, shutdownNow is not sufficient for graceful termination of an executor service. See boilerplate code given to you on the ExecutorService Javadoc. Or call close which pretty much implements that boilerplate.

"I was expecting that it would provide a snapshot of the map at a point of time" What gave you that impression?  And chaining/collision never affects the semantics of a map.

@LouisWasserman - Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html
Here keys that were added much earlier ends up missing, despite keys added much later are being returned as part of the keyset. This is the unexpected behavior.

Not transactional
ConcurrentHashMap is not a transactional database.
Update status is per key according to the documentatïon:

Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a
given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null)
retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.) For aggregate
operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect
insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, Iterators,
Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of
the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the
iterator/enumeration. They do not throw
ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be
used by only one thread at a time. Bear in mind that the results of
aggregate status methods including size, isEmpty, and containsValue
are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent
updates in other threads. Otherwise the results of these methods
reflect transient states that may be adequate for monitoring or
estimation purposes, but not for program control


By the way, if the OP wants a transactional database, they might consider adding to their project a pure Java database engine such as H2, Derby, or HSQLDB.

The question is not about true transactionality. Point is if a key is successfully added, then expectation was that it would be returned as part of the map keyset. However, that does not seem to be the case. Below is an exception from the above code "Subscriber 33 missing 80 keys! Result key range is [ key-0, key-1879]. However, many numbers in range [ key-1564, key-1789 ] are missing" Here keys that are added later are being returned in the keyset, but not the previous keys. This is the unexpected behavior.
@BasilBourque

I think that this part of above quote is relev: "However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time. Bear in mind that the results of aggregate status methods including size, isEmpty, and containsValue are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent updates in other threads. Otherwise the results of these methods reflect transient states that may be adequate for monitoring or estimation purposes, but not for program control".

This previous answer may be relvant too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67866437/721855
